# Get submit button value in PHP

Tags: php, button

I would like to test my button can get the current value from the date's textbox? I got the value of submit button but I couldn't find any code get name of the button. So what should I call I'm able to view the value?

```
$form_button_layout = '<button class="btn" name="oprf" value="view-log" type="submit">View</button>';

 <form class="well form-inline" method="post"<?= $form_action_override; ?>>
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I want to get the value after I press submit button.

Comment: It's not in `$_POST['oprf']`?

Comment: Value of your submit button???

Comment: Via javascript or PHP?

Comment: post your code inside <form> and </form> ..

Comment: Post the code. or if you want to keep your code confidential, at least create an image **clearly** depicting what you want to do and post it here...

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to get the value of 'oprf' above, then:

```
$value = $_POST['obrf'];
```

Should do it in php.

Comment: No I just want to show whether I get the value from the button or not.

Comment: On click of your `submit` button: `view-log`, you want to display the value of **WHAT**??

Comment: @elavarasanlee I'm using datepicker, just want to check the date I select have pass the value or not

Comment: `the date I select have pass the value` -> Not able to understand what that means...!!!

Comment: Do you want to get the value of a date field generated by a date picker when you press the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works consitently in all browsers. Better to work with a customized `name` attribute.

Comment: What doesn't work consistently? And isn't `name="oprf"` a customized name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
if(isset($_POST['oprf'])) {
 echo $_POST['oprf'];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add type property with submit `type="submit"` to button tag this will submit the form then receive the form inputs value in php script with super global variable `$_POST['input name']` or `$_GET[]` wdepends on from action property value by default GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if ($_POST['oprf'] == '' || $_POST['oprf'] == NULL) {
//this checks to see if there has been a value that was sent with the
//form
}
```

I usually use isset for cookies.